# Printing from arrays vs awk 'NR

Tags: command-line, awk

I am currently printing out values from vmstat stress tests using this:

```
  vmstat -a $INT $CNT | awk 'NR > 1 {print $13,$14,$15}'> vm.log_$D & sleep 5 && stress --vm $cores -t $seconds_to_run
```

I think it might be tidier to print them out in arrays but when I do, I always get a syntax error of { missing even when there isn't. How can I convert this to print the values of column $13, $14, $15 through using arrays rather than the way above?

The output of both should be the same but I feel the arrays look tidier in terms of output.

#### iostat output

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          17.74    1.77   31.43   25.05    0.00   24.02

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda              51.97      1349.36        32.86     392947       9568

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           9.18   78.57   12.24    0.00    0.00    0.00

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda               2.04        12.24         0.00         12          0
```

I would like for when I run it for only the percentage columns to be printed, not the kb read ones.

EDIT**********************************

sar -D output-I would like a suitable command to run alongside stress -hdd but this is the output which sar -D 1 10 gives.

```
    4296roryhbmc
    1944    rootal,
    3361    root
Tasks:     326total,
Cpu(s):25.7%us,54.1%sy,
Mem:2041916k
Swap:1046524kt    0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 268   957 
 34  17  49   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 279   679 
 49  31  21   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 334  1874 
  4   6  90   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 109   131 
 28  16  55   1   0   0|   0  4096B|   0     0 |   0     0 | 304   575 
 42  33  26   0   0   0|  20k  428k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 392  1343 
  4  10  86   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  81   124 
  8  12  57  22   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 113   193 
  2   9  66  22   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  74   126 
  4  12  84   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  92   140 
  8  21  54  17   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 129   286 
  7  11  48  33   0  
*******************************
* Choose from the following: *
*******************************
* [1] Stress the CPU. *
* [2] Stress the Memory(RAM). *
* [3] Stress the disk drive. *
* [4] Stress the  hard disk drive. *
Press A to quit.
************************
Enter your menu choice [1-4]:
```

How can I edit it so it will only show this?

```
$ sar -d

SunOS unknown 5.10 Generic_118822-23 sun4u    01/22/2006

00:00:01   device       %busy   avque   r+w/s  blks/s  avwait  avserv
. cut ...
14:00:02   dad0             31     0.6      78   16102     1.9     5.3
           dad0,c            0     0.0       0       0     0.0     0.0
           dad0,h           31     0.6      78   16102     1.9     5.3
           dad1              0     0.0       0       1     1.6     1.3
           dad1,a            0     0.0       0       1     1.6     1.3
           dad1,b            0     0.0       0       0     0.0     0.0
           dad1,c            0     0.0       0       0     0.0     0.0
```

source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-perfmonsar.html

Comment: Arrays of what? Bash arrays? Awk arrays?

Comment: output in awk arrays

Comment: And how would that be an improvement?

Comment: Please explain/give an example of what you mean by "arrays look tidier in terms of output" - it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: when I print the value in an array(in examples I have that don't use stress) the values are always output in a straight vertical lines. When I use the other method NR > 1 {print $13,$14,$15} they values sometimes run into one another

Comment: What you probably want is the `column` command.

Comment: Have you tried just setting awk's output field separator to tab instead of space? `awk 'NR > 1 {OFS="\t"; print $13,$14,$15}'`

Comment: I will try those now. Does putting it in arrays make any difference to the output in terms of speed or anything? Is there any need to use arrays at all in bash or awk for any outputs?

Comment: None at all. The internal data structures you use to store information in a script have no effect on the way that data is printed. You could theoretically use arrays for this but it would just make your script harder to write, more unwieldy, longer and uglier and give no benefit whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with whether the data is stored within awk using an array or not.

As mentioned by @muru, you can re-format your data into columns using the `column` command

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print $13,$14,$15}' | column -t
```

Alternatively, just set awk's own *output field separator* to <kbd>TAB</kbd> instead of space directly

```
awk 'NR > 1 {OFS="\t"; print $13,$14,$15}'
```

For more complicated formatting requirements, you could replace the `print` statement by a `printf`, which would allow you to specify field-widths explicitly, e.g.

```
awk 'NR > 1 {printf "%4s%8s%8s\n",$13,$14,$15}'
```

---

For your `iostat` requirement, the first thing to note is that you can limit `iostat`'s output to only the CPU Utilization Report (omitting the Device Utilization Report) by adding the `-c` command line switch, e.g.

```
 iostat -c 1 10
```

Beyond that, if you want to skip the repeated blank and header lines, you could do something like

```
iostat -c 1 5 | awk '/^$/ || /^avg-cpu:/ {next}; {print}'
Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (T61p)  15-03-02    _x86_64_    (2 CPU)
          11.11    0.04    2.67    0.14    0.00   86.04
           2.53    0.00    1.01    0.00    0.00   96.46
           4.46    0.00    1.49    0.00    0.00   94.06
           2.99    0.00    1.00    0.50    0.00   95.52
           3.02    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00   96.48
```

or you could do something fancier to print only the *first* `%` header:

```
$ iostat -c 1 5 | awk '/^$/ || (/^avg-cpu:/ && a) {next}; NR>1 {a=1;print}'
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          11.11    0.04    2.67    0.14    0.00   86.04
           2.02    0.00    0.51    0.00    0.00   97.47
           4.04    0.00    0.51    0.00    0.00   95.45
           2.50    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00   96.50
           3.02    0.00    1.01    0.00    0.00   95.98
```

Comment: I'll try those now, how can I convert it to arrays anyway for my own records?

Comment: when I run it with vmstat and add cat.filename after, it outputs the filtered data ok. but when I run it with iostat or sar and do the same cat.filename, it outputs nothing. Is there an iostat-type command and a cpu-type command that will print ok with this filter?

Comment: How many fields are in your iostat output, and which ones are you trying to extract? Did you change the field indices (the `$13`,`$14` and so on) appropriately?

Comment: there are about six, I have adjusted it, although iostat has about two lines per iteration and so when I write it to text, it comes out messy even with the formatting. rather than print $1, $2 etc, is there a way to print the column name e.g. print nice % and skip all of the extra information?

Comment: Well there's no single 'magic formula' that will turn arbitrary command output into a chosen format - you will need to familiarize yourself with the various tools (sed, awk, perl, column, ...) and their parsing/pattern matching capabilities. If you want help with a specific requirement then you will need to post an example of input and desired output i.e. exactly what you want to turn into what.

Comment: `avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          12.37    0.00    9.28    0.00    0.00   78.35

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0 ` rather than print this, which is very messy for excel, I would like to just print certain column names like nice% and their number of iterations, so 10 nice columns for iostat 1 10, rather than the unwiedly mess that does print.

Comment: @paul please add the requirement to your question (using the `Edit` button) rather than via comments, which don't preserve the formatting

Comment: i have added it above

Comment: @paul please see updated answer

Comment: the iostat one works ok, would you know how to fix sar -d 1 10 in my edited answer above? I want a suitable command to run alongside stress --hdd